# 0.96 Inch LCD Display documentation

Tags: lcd

I have a brand new screen bought from [Amazon](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B08LMQ2YHV)
that has not came with any sort of documentation, how do I go about finding it?

Answer (score 1):

The brand is LINHU, which is so obscure that I couldn't even find a website.

My advice would be to contact an Arduino forum with more knowledgeable people. Because I'm sure whatever design this is based off, has been copied numerous times, and distributed by many vendors.

Also to steer away from obscure brands in favor of something slightly more expensive with proper documentation and support.

Comment: Or at least make sure the documentation exists on their website and download it before placing the order, instead of trusting that will be included.